# Python: threading + lock slows my app down considerably

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

Say I have a function that writes to a file. I also have a function that loops repeatedly reading from said file. I have both of these functions running in separate threads. (Actually I am reading/writing to registers via MDIO which is why I can't have both threads executing concurrently, only one or the other, but for the sake of simplicity, let's just say it's a file)

Now when I run the write function in isolation, it executes fairly quickly. However when I'm running threaded and have it acquire a lock before running, it seems to run extremely slow. Is this because the second thread (read function) is polling to acquire the lock? Is there any way to get around this?

I am currently just using a simple RLock, but am open to any change that would increase performance.

Edit: As an example, I will put a basic example of what's going on. The read thread is basically always running, but occasionally a separate thread will make a call to load. If I benchmark by running load from cmd prompt, running in a thread is at least 3x slower.

write thread:

```
import usbmpc # functions I made which access dll functions for hardware, etc

def load(self, lock):
    lock.acquire()
    f = open('file.txt','r')
    data = f.readlines()
    for x in data: 
        usbmpc.write(x)
    lock.release()
```

read thread:

```
import usbmpc

def read(self, lock): 
    addr = START_ADDR
    while True: 
        lock.acquire()
        data = usbmpc.read(addr)
        lock.release()
        addr += 4
        if addr > BUF_SIZE: addr = START_ADDR
```

Comment: In CPython, excluding GIL-releasing C (external) module, there is only one thread which "runs" at a time as only one thread is allowed to access the Python engine at a time. If the MDIO call doesn't release the GIL then the other function/lock *can't even get started* (that is, the Python code won't run) until the MDIO call is complete. (I am not how thread-aware MDIO is.)

Comment: I edited the post with an example. Are you saying once the write thread acquires the lock, the read thread will never execute? I was under the impression lock.acquire will poll until it acquires lock? What else could be slowing down the above code?

Comment: @Shaunak Amin I wasn't trying to say/imply that :-) Jut that CPython threading can't actually run multiple Python threads at the same (they lock internally on the GIL; only some instructions allow a Python thread to "yield") -- but this doesn't really apply with the above update as the locks are about the usbmpc access.

Comment: See http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html and if switching from RLock to Lock (is sufficient in this case) helps performance.

Comment: You can have a look at the wait() and notify() to make sure you are not landing in Producer-Consumer kind of problem. Is the call readlines() blocking for MDIO if there is nothing to read ?

Comment: Would adding a `time.sleep(0)` after each `lock.release()` help?

Comment: The issue isn't blocking. Each thread is getting time, but when the write thread obtains lock, its execution is slower than if I ran the function alone in a test environment (without the read thread polling for lock.acquire()). I've tried replacing RLock with Lock, didn't help performance (again, the issue isn't performance degraded by lock acquisition, but the neighboring threads stealing cpu cycles to poll for lock.acquire()). I've replaced threading with the select module; my conclusion is Python 2.7 threading module is complete trash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you use threading on a multicore machine?

If the answer is yes, then unless your Python version is 3.2+ you are going to suffer reduced performance when running threaded applications.

[David Beazly](http://www.dabeaz.com/GIL/) has put considerable effort to find what is going on with GIL on multicores and has made it easy for the rest of us to understand it too. Check his website and the resources there. Also you might want to see his [presentation](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf) at PyCon 2010. It is rather intresting.

To make a long story short, in Python 3.2, Antoine Pitrou [wrote a new GIL](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2009-October/093321.html) that has the same performance on single and multicore machines. In previous versions, the more cores/threads you have, the performance loss increases...

hope it helps :)

Comment: Both great answers, but these links gave me something good to go on. I had already decided before either answer to remove threading and handle scheduling myself (to avoid context switching hurting performance), as my needs are rather primitive. I wish I could checkmark both answers though.

Comment: I have since coded my own scheduler to prevent GIL context switching between threads, and a function previously taking 10+ minutes now takes 20 seconds (because of removal of several threads competing for cycles). THIS IS A WARNING: DO NOT USE THREADING ON PYTHON 2.x!!!

Comment: FYI, the link to the presentation in the answer is dead. It can be found here however: http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Why aren't you acquiring the lock in the writer for the duration of each write only? You're currently locking for the entire duration of the load function, the reader never gets in until the load function is completely done.

Secondly, you should be using context locks. Your current code is not thread safe:

```
def load(lock):
    for x in data:
        with lock:
            whatever.write(x)
```

The same goes for your reader. Use a context to hold the lock.

Thirdly, don't use an `RLock`. You know you don't need one, at no point does your read/write code need to reacquire, so don't give it that opportunity, you will be masking bugs.

The real answer is in several of the comments to your question: The GIL is causing some contention (assuming it isn't actually your misuse of locking). The Python `threading` module is fantastic, the GIL sometimes is not, but moreso, the complex behaviours it generates that are misunderstood. It's worth mentioning though that the mainstream belief that throwing threads at problems is not the panacea people believe it to be. It usually isn't the solution.