# Is Multithreading (in python) the same as calling the script multiple times?

Tags: python, multithreading

Let's assume we have some task, that could be divided into independent subtasks and we want to process these tasks in parallel on the same machine.

I read about multithreading and ran into [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5441992/641514), which describes GlobalInterpreterLocks. Since I do not understand fully how processes are handled under the hood, I got to ask:

Putting aside the gain of threading: **Is Multithreading (in my case in python) effectively the same as calling a script multiple times?**

I hope this question does not lead to far and its answer is understandable for someone whose knowledge about the things happening on the low levels of a computer are sparse. Thanks for any enlightening in this matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is Multithreading (in my case in python) effectivle the same as calling a script multiple times?

In a word, no.

Due to the [GIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock), in Python it is far easier to achieve true parallelism by using multiple processes than it is by using multiple threads. Calling the script multiple times (presumably with different arguments) is an example of using multiple processes. The [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module is another way to achieve parallelism by using multiple processes. Both are likely to give better performance than using threads.

If I were you, I'd probably consider [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) as the first choice for distributing work across cores.

Comment: "in Python it is far easier to achieve true parallelism by using multiple processes than it is by using multiple threads" & "Both are likely to give better performance than using threads"- It _does_ say **in Python**, but I just wanted clarification that this applies to Python, and not generally as well (since other posts that I've been reading don't mention the better performance of multi-processing vs multi-threading)

Answer (score 1):

It is not the same thing one is Multithreading while the other is opening separate process for one another:

here is a short explanation taken from [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/) :

> It is important to first define the differences between processes and
>   threads. Threads are different than processes in that they share
>   state, memory, and resources. This simple difference is both a
>   strength and a weakness for threads. On one hand, threads are
>   lightweight and easy to communicate with, but on the other hand, they
>   bring up a whole host of problems including deadlocks, race
>   conditions, and sheer complexity. Fortunately, due to both the GIL and
>   the queuing module, threading in Python is much less complex to
>   implement than in other languages.