# Python Multithreading with openCV with lock

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, opencv

I am pretty new to python, and have some questions about python threading and lock. (I use Python 2.7.12)

I referred to [this article](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/12/21/increasing-webcam-fps-with-python-and-opencv/) to read the video from a webcam with opencv in one thread, and the main thread calls the read() method shown below and acquires a frame to display/do some image processing. 
To prevent read() method being called while the frame is being written and vice versa, I implemented the lock. However, it significantly slowed down the program and I do not see why. Without lock, it runs great. 
I did a little research and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426533/python-threading-lock-slows-my-app-down-considerably) but not sure if the same thing applies to me.

- Is it because I am using python 2.7 and not using 3.2+?
- I read about GIL and assigning value being atomic. Is

  ```
  (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.stream.read()
  ```

  atomic? 
  Do I need even need a lock?

  ```
  class captureThread:
      def __init__(self, src=0):
          self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture(src)
          (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.stream.read()
          self.stopped = False
          self.lock = Lock()
      def start(self):
          Thread(target=self.update, args=()).start()
          return self
      def update(self):
          while True:
              if self.stopped:
                  return
              self.lock.acquire()
              try:
                  (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.stream.read()
              finally: 
                  self.lock.release()
      def read(self):
          self.lock.acquire()
          try: 
              grabbed=self.grabbed
              frame = self.frame
          finally: 
              self.lock.release()
          return grabbed,frame
      def stop(self):
          self.stopped = True
  ```

Comment: I am looking for a solution for this problem but with a C++ implementation. As far as I am concerned, the python data structure for the stream is already thread safe. Is there a need to wrap a mutex around this?